# Rendering the Navbar on every page except for the auth page in my React.js App

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react.js and currently I am coding a recipe/cookbook application. Currently I am stuck at something I thought would be easy but I can't seem to make work. I am trying to make it so that every page has the navbar component except for the welcome/login/register page(all in one page). My App.js returns the following:

```
<BrowserRouter>
<main className="main-content">
  <Switch>
  <AuthContext.Provider 
    value={{
        token: this.state.token, 
        userId: this.state.userId, 
        login: this.login, 
        logout: this.logout
      }}>
          {!this.state.token && <Redirect from="/" to="/auth" exact/>}
          {!this.state.token && <Route path="/auth" component={AuthPage} />}
          {this.state.token && <Redirect from="/" to="/landing" exact/>}
          {this.state.token && <Redirect from="/auth" to="/landing" exact/>}}

     <MainNav>
        {this.state.token && <Route path="/landing" component={LandingPage}/>}
        {this.state.token && <Route path="/cookbook" component={CookbookPage}/>}
        {this.state.token && <Route path="/recipeLookup" component={RecipeLookupPage} />}       
      </MainNav>  
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  </Switch>
</main>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Even though I wrap the routes that I want to have a nav with the < MainNav >, the nav shows up in all pages, specifically the auth page. I've tried a few things such as having 2  tags which works with having the navbar off of the auth page but then none of the other routes work anymore. I've also tried a few other solutions that I have researched but I could not get them to work on my application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Search the `authorized route` for react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could change display prop to none when route is equal login route.

Answer (score 0):

If you have auth route API you can check localStorage

```
{
localStorage.getItem('token') ? (
  <MainNav>
     <Route path="/landing" component={LandingPage}/>
     <Route path="/cookbook" component={CookbookPage}/>
     <Route path="/recipeLookup" component={RecipeLookupPage} />       
  </MainNav> 
) : (null)
}
```

or you can control it with state

```
{
this.state.token ? (
  <MainNav>
     <Route path="/landing" component={LandingPage}/>
     <Route path="/cookbook" component={CookbookPage}/>
     <Route path="/recipeLookup" component={RecipeLookupPage} />       
  </MainNav> 
) : (null)
}
```

also you can set private route for authorization like https://medium.com/@tomlarge/private-routes-with-react-router-dom-28e9f40c7146